# Accessing javascript (Jquery) variables from Apache Wicket

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, apache, wicket

I'm a noob learning Wicket/Jquery. I'm trying to access JavaScript (Jquery) variables from Wicket. Here's an example I'm working with:

```
        Component slider = new WebMarkupContainer("slider").add(new SliderBehavior(
            new SliderOptions().changeEvent("alert('clicked!')").orientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL).min(10).max(100).value(20)));
```

I'm implementing here a jqwicket slider example. Instead of the "alert('clicked!')" event I would like to read the value of the slider to the java. All help appreciated!!!

Comment: There is no thing such as a "jquery variable". jQuery is awesome but it's just a JavaScript library. So there are only JavaScript variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to combine jquery's "changeEvent" with the ajax request sending current slider value to your wicket component.

jqwicket contains example for doing this. for more information see AjaxSlider here:

http://code.google.com/p/jqwicket/source/browse/tags/jqwicket-demo-0.4/jqwicket-demo/src/main/java/net/javaforge/jqwicket/SliderPage.java

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/master/jdk-1.5-parent/jquery-parent/jquery-examples/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/jquery/demo/ui/Page4Slider.java