# Working with JQWicket's AjaxSlider

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, slider, wicket

Once again I'm gonna show my noobiness by asking about the basics. This follow-up question is related to thread: [Accessing javascript (Jquery) variables from Apache Wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139715/accessing-javascript-jquery-variables-from-apache-wicket)

I started to work with the AjaxSlider example, I have the value send back to me, but how do I render the slider component again with other parameters? I would like to change the maximum value that can be assigned to that AjaxSlider. Is there an api somewhere about this?

[the object for me is to create a label with percentages (from 0 to 100) and two sliders with which you can distribute the percentage as you please. E.g. let the user distribute money among men and women] This is the code I'm working with currently:

```
 add(new AjaxSlider("ajaxSlider1") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onValueChanged(AjaxRequestTarget target, int newValue) {

        System.out.println("selected_value: "+newValue);

    }
});
```

The original example can be found here: [AjaxSliderExample](http://code.google.com/p/jqwicket/source/browse/tags/jqwicket-demo-0.4/jqwicket-demo/src/main/java/net/javaforge/jqwicket/SliderPage.java)

Appreciate all the help and thank you for reading this far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the underlying jqwicket's `SliderBehavior` from within the `onValueChanged(..)` method (e.g. create a getter for the `SliderBehavior` in the `AjaxSlider` or make it protected). After this you can change the maximum value of the slider like this:

```
@Override
public void onValueChanged(AjaxRequestTarget target, int newValue) {
   this.sliderBehavior.option(target, "'max'", "10");
}
```

In this way you can manipulate all available slider options (see jqwicket's `SliderOptions` class or original JQuery UI Slider documentation).

Note! You can alternatively inherit jqwicket's predefined `SliderWebMarkupContainer` to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `AjaxSlider`, however if an Ajax request wants to re-render any component, the component has to be added to the `AjaxRequestTarget`.

(A restriction on this is that only components with markup ids can be redrawn by an Ajax request. This means that you have to call `setOutputMarkupId( true )` on these components when you create them.