# How to stop JQWicket's AjaxSlider from sliding right?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, slider, wicket

I'm a noob to RIA-development and working with the [JQWicket's Ajax Slider Example](http://code.google.com/p/jqwicket/source/browse/tags/jqwicket-demo-0.4/jqwicket-demo/src/main/java/net/javaforge/jqwicket/SliderPage.java).

I'm trying to implement a page of two Ajax sliders and a counter. The idea is that the user can spread the the counter value to the sliders, but not exceed the value of the counter. I.e. the slider should stop sliding right when the counter reaches 0.

Example 1:
Counter: 100 (%)

Slider Men:       |----------| 0 (%)
Slider Women: |----------| 0 (%)

Example 2:
Counter: 0 (%)

Slider Men:       |--x-------| 30 (%) <-- (both of the slider would stop sliding
Slider Women: |------x---| 70 (%) <--  to right at counter = 0)

Now, I dont want to disable the slider, since I want it to slide left still. I just want it stop sliding right. How can I implement the stop-behavior for the sliders? Is it even possible with JQWicket Slider implementation?

All help greatly appreciated and I want to thank you for even reading this far! :)

(if you're a noob like me trying to figure out pretty much the same thing, you might want to check out also my previous questions and the great answers I got about the subject: 
[implementing-javascript-events-to-wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212537/implementing-javascript-events-to-wicket) and 
[working-with-jqwickets-ajaxsliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165191/working-with-jqwickets-ajaxslider)
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the value of the slider inside the onValueChanged method and (re)set it if the user set a value that is not inside your given range.

Comment: I can implement the slider so, that the counter shows zero and slider value no longer increases when counter reaches zero but for usability, I would like to stop the slider from moving to the other direction. I'm just not sure if that's even possible with this particular slider.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible at all. As long as I understand you want the user to drag the slider handle and if the handle reaches a given value you want to stop the moving of the slider while the user is still drags it? I'm afraid you can only achieve this if you build a special slider that is only a slider inside your given range and you have to draw a 'virtual slider range' for the range where the user can't drag. But this is nothing that can be done using wicket directly. I think you have to build it with jquery or whatever javascript framework want you use.